# A tag for Earth's rotation

Tags: discussion, tags

What about a tag like [earth-rotation](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earth-rotation) (synonym [rotation](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotation) maybe)?. For [several questions](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/search?q=rotation) I think something like this one is missing.

Comment: The [tag:feature-request] tag is wrong here, you should replace it with [tag:tags].

Comment: "Geodesy" covers rotation of the whole planet. "Geodynamics" covers rotation within the layers. These should be kept separate. "Earth-rotation" is ambiguous.